# How to communicate between React and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a code where you can do something like

React:

```
class app extends React.Component{
//states and stuff
render(){
<div>
<p className = "ellipse" x = {this.state.x} y={this.state.y} rx={this.state.rx} ry={this.state.ry}/>
<div/>

}
}
```

css

```
.ellipse{
x:(the input x)
y:(the input y)
rx:(the input rx)
ry:(the input ry)
}
```

This would create an ellipse centered at x,y with horizontal radius rx, and vertical radius ry

Comment: What is this CSS property? `x`,`y`,`rx`,`ry`?

Comment: This looks like SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a style object to your React components.

But note, the CSS attributes should be camel-cased.
It's `marginLeft` and `paddingLeft`.

And then, you could hook up your style object to your react state.

Example :-

```
const [padding, setPadding] = React.useState(10);

<div style={{ paddingLeft: `${padding}px` }} />
```

Comment: ok, thank you! If you have time, may i ask what the corresponding CSS code would look like or is this completely independent?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't very clear. Is it necessary to have css code in App.css to be able to use `<div style={{ paddingLeft: `${padding}px` }} />` or is it independent of anything in the css file

Comment: Do check this out. -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pzxs3f?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: may i ask why this doesn't work                                                                              `return <h1 style = {{position:'absolute', borderRadius:'50%/50%',border:"solid 5px #f00",width:12,height:13,marginTop:12,marginLeft:32}}/>`

Comment: It's showing up here. Check this out -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pzxs3f?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Hey, this is an unrelated question, but do you have any advice for putting a react flask app on an ec2 server on aws?

Answer (score 2):

Many concepts in React are different to Vanilla Javascript, many things you can easily achieve in JS, for example, css `hover` effect, pseudo elements `before` `after`, are achieved in a completely difference way in React, here I would include some general methods to style a component.

relative reading:

- [How to style a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)
- [styling and css](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)
- [5 ways to style react component](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-style-react-components-in-2019-30f1ccc2b5b)

---

### 1. Plugin: styled-component

`styled component` is the number one plugin I love in React. to install:

`npm install --save styled-components`

if you are using typescript, run following commands:

`npm install --save @types/styled-components`

after installing, you can easily style component, even involving complex stuff such as `:hover`, `::before`, `::before:hover`, take following as an example:

```js
function CSSPropertiesToComponent(dict:React.CSSProperties){
    let str = '';
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)){
        let clo = '';
        key.split('').forEach(lt=>{
            if(lt.toUpperCase() === lt){
                clo += '-' + lt.toLowerCase();
            }else{
                clo += lt;
            }
        });
        str += clo + ':' + value + ';';
    }
    return str;
}

class Movie extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public static style:React.CSSProperties|object = {
        width: "300px",
        height: "120px",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: "20px",
        filter: "drop-shadow(0px 1px 3px #6d6d6d)",
        WebkitFilter: "drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #6d6d6d)",
        backgroundColor: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16),
        fontSize: '2.5rem',
        margin: '20px',
        color: '#fff',
    }

    render():JSX.Element{
        let StyledMovie = styled.div`
            ${CSSPropertiesToComponent(Movie.style)}
        `;

        return (
            <>
                <StyledMovie>{this.props.title}</StyledMovie>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

the major advantage of this method, is that you can leave out the styling for future import.

---

### 2. if you don't want to install plugin, you can directly add style to the component

**Notice: Any class name extends form React.Component must be capitalized**

```js
class Ellipse extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let style:React.CSSProperties|object = {
            width: '200px',
            height: '150px',
            border: '1px solid',
        };

        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <p style={style} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

However, it is **extremely hard to add hover effect**, what you need to do, instead, is to manually trigger mouse event, for example:

```js
class Ellipse extends React.Component{
    props: React.ComponentProps<any>;
    state: React.ComponentState;

    public static style:React.CSSProperties|object = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '150px',
        border: '1px solid',
    };

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        // bind the method otherwise class method won't have access to this keyword
        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
        this.state = {style: Object.assign({}, Ellipse.style)}
    }

    hide(){
        this.setState({style: Object.assign({}, Ellipse.style, {visibility: 'hidden'})});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <p style={this.state.style} onMouseMove={this.hide} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```